# jQuery - Search as you type on page just like cpanel search

Tags: jquery, search, find, jquery-filter

I am looking for a functionality just like cpanel search. Where as you type in search box, the similar content stays and rest disappears. Example

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
<div>good</div>
<div>bad</div>
<input type="text" name="search">
```

Now as I start typing "he". Only hello display and rest of the divs goes to display:none;

Is it possible? People who have seen Cpanel search box, knows what I am asking. I have been looking around for this but could not find anything similar to it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure pretty simple, just use the `keyup` `event` and toggle the `<div>`'s accordingly

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCTqC/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
  <div>good</div>
  <div>bad</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function(event){
        var keyCode = event.which; // check which key was pressed
        var term = $(this).val();
        $('#example').children().hide(); // hide all
        $('#example').children(':Contains("' + term + '")').show(); // toggle based on term
    });
 });​

 $.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) { 
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
 };
```

Comment: Great! It works. Ok so couple of more tweaks. It is working as case sensitive. I want it to work without being case sensitive and also ignore characters like - / ( ) etc both inside search box and the text inside div.

Comment: You could extend the functionality of the contains selector to make it case insensitive. You can also check which key was pressed and act accordingly. Updated my answer. Please mark don't forget to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I will surely do that but how can I remove the case sensitivity? Right now if I search anything in upper case, result is nil

Comment: I already answered that, look at the updated answer / example, not to mention my comment.

Comment: I want to ignore the uppercase not employ it. Thanks!

Comment: What? It's case insensitive right now. It's not altering the case in the textbox or div.

Comment: I guess you didnt understand. The first solution you provided me is case sensitive by default. In your 2nd solution again you added a case sensitive check. I do not want case sensitive search.

Comment: NO, THE SECOND SOLUTION IS CASE **INSENSITIVE**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12512/discussion-between-john-and-gabe)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's possible.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQFQ5/2/

This is the function that makes it work:

```
$('input').bind('keyup',function(){
  var selfVal = $(this).val()
  var compareDivs = $('div');
  compareDivs.each(function(){
     var divVal = $(this).text().toString();
     if (divVal.indexOf(selfVal)<0)
         $(this).fadeOut();
     else
         $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});​
```